# Swift - Get Constraints by reference or loop through the property's constraint?

Tags: ios, swift

```
@IBOutlet weak var customView: UIView!
```

Let say I have a UIView in Storyboard named `customView` like that and it has height constraint set up before in the storyboard.

I was wondering are there any performance differences if I want to change the height with these method:

**Storyboard Reference**

```
@IBOutlet weak var customViewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!  
func ChangeConstraint() {
    customViewHeightConstraint.constant = newValue
}
```

**Loop through the constraints**

```
for constraint in customView.constraints where constraint.firstAttribute == . height {
    constraint.constant = newValue
}
```

Comment: I always opt for references, as you know exactly which constraint you're getting - there are no surprises.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a tradeoff between the 2 approaches in terms of processing time & memory , first approach creates a new var but 1 step to set , second approach has no vars but a loop for all height constraints inside the view ( where may exist height constraints with Chilterns ) , so according to what makes more sense to your app select one , anyway i recommend the first approach

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the performance difference, if any, is insignificant.

I would definitely choose the first approach with the storyboard reference. Makes the connection between the changed constraint and your intent more explicit.